# Can we insert logic code in Dreamweaver (.PHP)?

Tags: java, php, dreamweaver

For those who are familiar with Dreamweaver and PHP, I would like to ask whether we can insert logic code such as looping in Java into Dreamweaver.

As I need to build a system that works like this:

A patient can make appointment into the system and get early appointment's time if his/her disease is more critical than others. Means that, he/she get the early slot time for appointments.

Therefore, I need to insert some logic code into my system that is built using Dreamweaver.

Is that possible?

Thank You .

Comment: Yes. You can do that on php.

Comment: Are you sure? as my friend said that only DW that using JSP can insert logic code. How can I put the logic code? Is there any syntax that must be put into the DW?

Comment: If the system is built on php, you can add logic such as loop. Also, If the code is php, you can code it any text base editor, even on notepad (not necessarily on DW)

Comment: DW is just a text editor at its core. So yes, you can do this with DW, just as you can with any other editor. DW might do some syntax analysis, but it's worth being aware that the only thing that runs the code is the PHP intepreter, which is a completely separate thing from DW.

Comment: thank you to all ! I will study first then , if got question, hope all of you will answer it. :)